# Как можно уйти от больших чисел?

Tags: c#

Я написал функцию, которая преобразует логическое условие в математическое выражение.
Пример :

Логическое:
`fling = 1 and fland=1 and [in] in ( 1, 2, 2 , 3,'sadsadsada')`

Математический эквивалент: `(2858*468*2808*468*1003 * (468+470+470+472+9649)  )`

По некоторому правилу я заменяю ключевые слова на + и *.

Неключевые слова я преобразую следующим образом:

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= word.Length; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + (word[i - 1] * i);//Умножаем код символа на его позицию
            }
```

Потом я скармливаю полученное математическое выражение сюда:

```
ScriptControl sc = new ScriptControl { Language = "VBScript" };    
string expression = str;
            return (long)this.sc.Eval(expression);
```

Полученные результаты я сравниваю и на основании этого я делаю вывод равны ли логические выражения или нет:

Эти равны:

```
fling = 1 and fland=1 and [in] in ( 1, 2, 2 , 3,'sadsadsada')

[in] in ( 1, 2, 2 , 3,'sadsadsada') and fling=1 and fland = 1
```

А эти нет:

```
field=1 and field2=2

field=1 or field2=2
```

Этот подход работает, но возвращаются здоровенные числа... Как можно уйти от них в моей текущей реализации?

Comment: думаю, Вам нужно научится парсить подобные выражения и строить ast дерево. А потом просто сравнивать два дерева.

Comment: Не посоветуете книгу или статью на русском?

Comment: ищите "книгу дракона". А также изучайте английский.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы по большому счёту вычисляете хэш от математического выражения. При этом, как я понимаю, вы пользуетесь коммутативностью для того, чтобы выражения, отличающиеся лишь порядком слагаемых/сомножителей/элементов списка, имели одинаковый хэш.

Это значит, что вам подойдёт любая коммутативная операция. Например, XOR (которая кодируется как `^`). С другой стороны, я не вижу проблемы в получении «больших» чисел: всё равно все числа будут считаться по модулю 2³², так что переполнения не будет.

Обратите внимание на то, что вы пользуетесь очень небезопасной функцией `Eval`. Если строка поставляется злонамеренным пользователем, он сможет выполнить произвольный код на вашей системе, если ваша фильтрация окажется несовершенной.

Кстати говоря, вы *не можете* делать вывод о равенстве математических выражений на основе хеш-функции! Оно и понятно: ведь математических выражений бесконечно много, а значений вашей хэш-функции не больше, чем 2³². Вы можете лишь сделать вывод, что выражения не равны, если у них различные хэши. (Да и то с поправкой на коммутативность: различные хэши могут вполне означать одинаковые *по сути* функции!) Если же хэши равны, из этого **не следует**, что выражения совпадают, даже с точностью до перестановки.